# Word search in a matrix leetcode solution not working

Tags: python, algorithm

> Given a 2D board and a word, find if the word exists in the grid.
>
> The word can be constructed from letters of sequentially adjacent
> cell, where "adjacent" cells are those horizontally or vertically
> neighboring. The same letter cell may not be used more than once.
>
> For example, Given
>
> ```
> board = [   ['A','B','C','E'],   ['S','F','C','S'],   ['A','D','E','E'] ]
>
> word = "ABCCED", -> returns true
>
> word = "SEE", -> returns true
>
> word = "ABCB", -> returns false
> ```

This is a typical DFS + backtracking solution. It compares `board[row][col]` with `word[start]`. If they match, change `board[row][col]` to `‘#’` to mark it as visited. Then move to the next one (i.e. `word[start + 1]`) and compare it to the current neighbors (doing it by recursion).

Below is my code which is not working. I tried debugging but I feel there is off by one error somewhere which I am not able to track.

```
class Solution(object):
    def exist(self, board, word):
        def match(board, word, r, c, index):
            if r < 0 or r >= len(board) or c < 0 or c >= len(board[0]) or index < 0 or index > len(word):
                return False
            if index == len(word):
                return True
            directions = [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]
            for x, y in directions:
                tmp = board[r][c]
                board[r][c] = "#"
                if tmp == word[index] and match(board, word, r+x, r+y, index+1):
                    return True
                board[r][c] = tmp
            return False
        
        """
        :type board: List[List[str]]
        :type word: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if board == word:
            return True
        if not board and word or board and not word:
            return False
        for r in range(len(board)):
            for c in range(len(board[0])):
                if match(board, word, r, c, 0):
                    return True
        return False
```

Comment: Is there an actual error message you can share with us or does your implementation not lead to the desired result?

Comment: "r+y" should be "c+y"

Answer (score 0):

It is fixed by following @jeff suggestions from the comments to this question i.e. "r+y" should be "c+y".